# How to add AwesomeFontFX Icon Pack to JavaFX Project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, javafx, icons, scenebuilder

I am creating a mini-JavaFX project and wanted to use the Awesome Font Icon Pack.I loaded the fontawesomefx-8.9 using the Scenebuilder and opened the FXML in it and loaded two icons in it, also added the JAR file in External Libraries in IntelliJ but when I run the code it gives a ClassNotFoundException for de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView. What should I do?

I removed the two Icons and the code runs fine. I searched many places but it only showed to add the JAR files to external libraries and nothing. I am using JDK 12 , JavaFX 12 and Scenebuilder 11.0.

FXML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<fx:root alignment="center" hgap="10" type="GridPane" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Click Me!!!">
         <opaqueInsets>
            <Insets left="5.0" />
         </opaqueInsets></Button>
      <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="CIRCLE" />
   </children>
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
</fx:root>
```

Controller Class

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    }

Module-Info.java

module Practice {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens sample;
}
```

Main Class

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Error

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\java.exe" --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=7604:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -p "E:\Java Programs\javafx-sdk-12.0.2\lib\javafx.base.jar;E:\Java Programs\javafx-sdk-12.0.2\lib\javafx.graphics.jar;E:\Java Programs\JavaFX\Practice\out\production\Practice;E:\Java Programs\javafx-sdk-12.0.2\lib\javafx-swt.jar;E:\Java Programs\javafx-sdk-12.0.2\lib\javafx.controls.jar;E:\Java Programs\javafx-sdk-12.0.2\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;E:\Java Programs\javafx-sdk-12.0.2\lib\javafx.media.jar;E:\Java Programs\javafx-sdk-12.0.2\lib\javafx.swing.jar;E:\Java Programs\javafx-sdk-12.0.2\lib\javafx.web.jar;E:\Java Programs\JavaFX\fontawesomefx-8.9.jar" -m Practice/sample.Main
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/E:/Java%20Programs/JavaFX/Practice/out/production/Practice/sample/sample.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2863)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2676)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2542)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at Practice/sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2931)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2920)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2861)
    ... 20 more
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using Java and JavaFX 12, you should use a valid FontAwesomeFX version: 11.0.0.

You can find it here: https://bintray.com/jerady/maven/FontAwesomeFX/11.0.0

If you are using Maven or Gradle, you can just include the FontAwesome dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-11"
}
```

That will also include `de.jensd:fontawesomefx-commons:11.0`.

If you don't use Maven/Gradle, you will have to download them from [here](https://bintray.com/jerady/maven/download_file?file_path=de%2Fjensd%2Ffontawesomefx-commons%2F11.0%2Ffontawesomefx-commons-11.0.jar) and [here](https://bintray.com/jerady/maven/download_file?file_path=de%2Fjensd%2Ffontawesomefx-fontawesome%2F4.7.0-11%2Ffontawesomefx-fontawesome-4.7.0-11.jar), and include them in your project.

Next step: since you have a modular application, your module descriptor should contain all the modules that your project *requires*.

Therefore your `module-info` should include the `fontawesome` module:

```
module Practice {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires de.jensd.fx.fontawesomefx.fontawesome;

    opens sample to javafx.fxml;
    exports sample;
}
```

Now your project will have all the required dependencies and will work.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked with JavaFX. I had earlier tried with Gradle and it also worked. Do you also know how to get it work other Font Packs such as Ikonli i.e what modules should I also include in the module-info file.

Comment: Just give it a try, it should be exactly the same with each module. IntelliJ should help you with hints about the module names, once you add the dependencies. If you have more issues, you can post a new question with them.

Comment: I mean to say the modules only in JavaFX project without Gradle or Maven.

Comment: Check the [FontAwesomeFX](https://bintray.com/jerady/maven/FontAwesomeFX/11.0.0) link I posted, you'll find there all the artifacts.